# How to remove html tags when getting reponse using HttpURLConnection and org.json library in Java?

Tags: java, api, httpurlconnection, org.json

I am using the following code to retreive information from API

```
HttpURLConnection connection;
```

..

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        responseContent.append(line);
}
reader.close();
```

Then I convert the reponse to string

```
String responseBody = responseContent.toString();
```

After that I use org.json library to parse the information

```
JSONObject ob = new JSONObject(responseBody);
JSONArray Information = ob.getJSONArray("info");

for (int i = 0; i < Information.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject data= Information.getJSONObject(i);
                
    String dataName= data.getString("data_name");
}
```

As result I obtained some texts with html tags when I print dataName values, for example:

```
content name<sup></sup>
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved

I used the Java Jsoup library to read the HTML tags.

Best regards.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).